# Checking if someone stayed in a hotel during a certain month, SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem I have been working on, and I tried several ways and do not think I have the right answer. I am trying to see if someone stayed in a hotel during a certain month. The issue I am running into is, if they started their stay before that month, and ended after that specific month.

The schema I have is:

- Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dataFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
- Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)

The SQL query I have so far is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Guest
WHERE guestNo IN (SELECT guestNo 
                  FROM Booking
                  WHERE (dateFrom >= “11/01/16” AND dateTo <= “11/30/16”)
                     OR (dateFrom >= "10/01/16" AND dateTo <= "11/01/16")
                     OR (dateFrom "11/30/16" AND dateTo <= "12/31/16")
```

However I think this will fail because of someone not staying the whole time through October. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (That is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: It's not a specific DBMS, it is just logic I am trying to work through. I know it is not standard SQL that will work if you type it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to catch stays that start on the previous month or extend to the next month, using the `overlaps` operator is a bit easier:

```
select *
from guests g
where exists (select *
              from booking b
              where (b.datefrom, b.dateto) overlaps (date '2016-11-01', date '2016-11-30')
                and b.guestno = g.guestno);
```

Comment: I think this makes the most sense. Since it handles all options I need to check.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct logic for any overlap during the month:

```
select g.*
from guests g
where not exists (select 1
                  from booking b
                  where b.guestno = g.guestno and
                        b.datefrom <= '2016-11-30' and
                        b.dateto >= '2016-11-01'
                 );
```

The stay overlaps with the month if it starts on or before the end of the month and ends on or after the beginning of the month.

Comment: I understand the whole statement besides the "select 1" what will that grab?

Comment: This is a NOT EXISTS subquery.  The value being selected doesn't matter.  I always use 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the start and end dates of a specific month fall between From and To dates

```
SELECT * 
FROM Booking 
WHERE ('2016-11-01' BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo)
OR ('2016-11-30' BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo)
OR (dateFrom >= '2016-11-01' AND dateTo <= '2016-11-30')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just check from October 1st to December 31